# A user is taking questions from MSDN forums, asking them on SO, and posting the SO answers back on MSDN

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, attribution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816683/index-to-speed-up-delete
taken from
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/00667b94-1fb5-4238-b169-c596a2ae25ed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816023/sys-dm-fts-parser-permission
taken from
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/a3ec4602-e0be-48f5-92ad-2eb25a6befc5

Comment: He's gaming two websites at once. He's a genius.

Comment: he didn't crospost. He takes some other user's question, ask it on SO, then posts back the SO answer *as his own answer* on MSDN

Comment: @TheLQ, the real problem here is that the user is not following the attribution rules: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/

Comment: This user appears to be doing it with several different accounts, too. Very nice.

Comment: Another one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816377/posting-txt-excel-files

Comment: @Pop: The attribution rules apply to the SO answers but MSDN forums don't come with a cc-wiki license.  Their content is copyrighted, period, so copying their questions is actually an infringement.

Comment: @Aaro, thanks for pointing that out. I don't know anything about MSDN's rules, though I think they're off-topic here. If we were on Meta MSDN instead of Meta SO, I'm sure I'd be much more upset.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/ed85fb0b-55db-474d-a45c-d715d659b0a8/#6157a812-82f8-473a-a689-d4217e1fbc13 -> taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787986/need-an-idea-for-doing-bulk-compare-and-insert

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/6013bdf2-1452-4495-865a-1bfcc8b361d0/#5f17fd95-16d0-40eb-b587-db35e44bdb69 -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815502/stored-procedure-when-to-use-output-parameter-vs-return-variable/3815545#3815545

Comment: More: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/add693eb-0728-4e4f-88dd-ab427d7c9c78 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815883/copy-reports-to-a-different-folder-on-report-server

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/d48d36de-0dff-4dc5-b52c-c56e4264056a and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808086/drop-tables-by-date-it-were-created

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/695fa7cd-7645-47ab-96e8-3a342441be98 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807251/is-this-stored-procedure-correct

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/50e3049b-f053-4e8f-acf0-37eb2bd7a7cf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789978/manipulate-a-dataset-in-a-gauge

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/1cf24bc1-ebc5-4050-956c-d21d732b21a6 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788461/replacing-group-by-with-row-numberpartition-by

Comment: @Pop: Anybody posting copyrighted content on an SE site is relevant.  If it constitutes copyright infringement then the content needs to be removed.

Comment: This one is somewhat amusing: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/a4e47578-e30b-41d8-ba23-6a92c2504e26/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781787/multiple-dates-query — it was answered by [Fritz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/455972/fritz), and the jerk kept Fritz's name in the answer when he pasted it over there. So now they think his name is Fritz…

Comment: @Popular, @Aarobot: it's particularly true when, as in this case, someone appears to be taking their content wholesale. I don't think SO will get a takedown letter, but I wouldn't be the slightest bit surprised to find out MS had automated bots doing just that.

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2010/09/28/plagiarizing-forum-answers/ I'll try to contact MSDN moderators tomorrow.

Comment: @Aarobot, I figured that'd be taken care of as a matter of course, but point well taken.

Comment: @Dori, you are a __machine__. I mean that in the nicest possible way. What's your strategy for finding those?

Comment: @Remus, you, too, are a machine. (Separate comment so the notifier doesn't ignore you.)

Comment: @Popular - @Remus's last two additions were by two more users. For each of those users, I ➀ opened all their other questions, ➁ copied the title of each, and ➂ pasted it into the search box at [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/categories). In every case, I found an exact recent match. Sadly, there's no ➃ Profit!, but thank you for the compliment… :-)

Comment: I did the opposite: I took the MSDN activity of 'Learning_SQL' and searched google for some verbatim of his answer. Every one I tried was a SO original...

Comment: The other users are http://stackoverflow.com/users/457450 and http://stackoverflow.com/users/456566, it appears. Possibly others. I'm leaving them alone because my head is kind of in a fog right now and I don't want to accidentally use the mod lasers on an undeserving victim.

Comment: The questions asked by the first account mentioned were all deleted, so for us low-rep users, this is the account in question: http://stackoverflow.com/users/460979/

Answer (score 15):

This is a flagrant violation of terms (certainly ours, and probably MSDN's too). I won't go into details here (public flogging etc), but it is being dealt with.

To make it clear: no, this will not be tolerated.

Answer (score 10):

Totally uncool, but easy to fix:

#### Bad

> *I asked someone about your question and he gave me the following answer.*
>
> [copy/paste of post with no attribution]

#### Good

> *I asked your question on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) (which is really a much better site than this one). Here's the answer I got:*
>
> [copy/paste of post with proper attribution and link]

Comment: True, that would fix the problem with copying from SO to MSDN, but it wouldn't fix the problem of copying from MSDN to SO.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a pretty clear violation of the licensing protecting user contributions.  (Links at the bottom of the page or, if you're lazy, [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/))