# Is it fine if I post a link to a question as a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

So I have seen this question on google groups and I think is a good question. Now without going through the trouble of copy pasting the entire question, is it okay if I just post the link to the question in my question and hope for an answer or is it not the SO way?

Comment: Just love it when my questions get downvoted for no apparent reason! :)

Comment: i think people sometimes perceive the question as the intent. if they disagree with the perceived intent, they downvote it. if one were to ask "can i reuse so content without attribution?" the question would be downvoted, even if it is a legitimate and useful question

Comment: Yeah, thats actually my point... Being a little sarcastic here, at the cost of further down-votes.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should copy-paste the question. Urls have a way of dying suddenly on the internet that could defeat the reusability of your question; site owner changing the way slugs are implemented, or the question id, group closing down, wiped out, etc...

I would recommend the following:

- ask for permission to the original asker
- copy-paste (with edits to keep everything pretty)
- link back to original question

Comment: k thanks... Seems like a reasonable suggestion... Thing is I asked the question on google groups, been some time with no reply... Feeling lazy to format the question on SO... So I was wondering if just providing a link is fine. :)

Answer (score 9):

Not the Stack Overflow way. Questions on SO should stand on their own.

Comment: ...after searchign SO for a possible similar existing question.

Comment: Pretty sure the question doesn't exist on SO.

Comment: @Shouvik: If you do repost the question, be sure to note where it came from. There was a [kerfuffle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65954/a-user-is-taking-questions-from-msdn-forums-asking-them-on-so-and-posting-the-s) a little while ago about questions and answers reposted from MSDN without attribution.

Comment: Yeah well that is not a problem, if I am posting the link itself as the question... People clearly know where the site is taking them... :) Anyway, get the picture... Thanks.