# I need rep to disagree!

Tags: discussion, down-votes

As you can see I have 45 rep on my Meta Stack Overflow account. I need 125 points when I need to disagree with someone's idea as they are blatantly stupid and I wish to remain anonymous.

But sadly I have absolute never had the good luck to have [not stupid ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66533/is-it-fine-if-i-post-a-link-to-a-question-as-a-question), so most of the times I just [disagreed a lot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work#47635), and that further kills my scope to actually do what I intend to, as I have stated above.

So to sum it up, if I am dumb could I not disagree with someone's idea? (anonymously of course)

PS: If you have not understood what I am aiming at, to blatantly put it, I don't agree with the method employed by Meta Stack Overflow to disagree with people. Also, by having so many downvotes of my really dumb questions, it makes me feel bad about me. I would like to ask for some other way like having a disagree meter! =)
I really hope people don't show their disagreement by voting on this question! ;)

EDIT:
People seem to misinterpret my suggestion or take it for its face value, or my English is crap (not my first language). So what I am trying to say is, downvoting, according to me, is like shunning a person! It's unacceptable unless the person deserves to be shunned. I would like some kind of check in place to see that it's not equated to bullying. If you like to get judgmental, leave a comment and then downvote or else don't do it at all.

Comment: Stop thinking about downvoting like it is shunning you, then. If you get a downvote with no comment, see what you can divine about your post to fix it. If you can't divine anything, shrug it off and go about your normal day. Because for everyone else, downvoting is a *perfectly acceptable measure with utility for the site meant to mark posts, not people*.

Comment: I have been downvote 4 times on this post, and upvoted thrice already! Little hard to just *shrug it off*, but ur right, I should go about my normal day after that... :)

Comment: @Shouvik  downvoting on Meta means something else altogether anyway, it's merely a sign of disagreement with the suggestion.

Comment: @Pekka then all I would like to point out is, that associating rep with privileges might not be the best practice... Have given rest to this topic though.. Accepted the fact that its pretty hard to be a privileged member of SO and have a life... :P :)

Comment: @Shouvik  As said, downvoting is not an attack on your person, nor a judgement on the quality of your question. It is a **vote of disagreement** with the measure(s) suggested in the question. Brilliant feature suggestions have been downvoted to oblivion on Meta because people didn't like the suggestion. If you can't deal with that, Meta isn't for you. If gaining reputation leads to you not having a life, then maybe SO isn't for you, either. :)

Comment: @Pekka Please don't take offence to my statements! I did realize the purpose of meta, and see the point to downvoting but don't necessarily agree with it. :) As for not having a life, well, I would say it was an ill-conceived jest, one I would like to retract and apologies for because I do realize how the interpretations may vary! Sorry.

Comment: @Shouvik yeah, no problem. I must say I agree with what you say about down-voting - votes on feature requests should clearly be labeled as a "yea" / "nay" thing, and disconnected from reputation... Meta reputation is more or less meaningless anyway.

Answer (score 7):

In the meantime, you can disagree with them by voting up some other answer instead!

Some info on downvoting:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Yeah, you missed the point! I don't want people downvoting me... =(

Comment: @Shou, you want to downvote and not be downvoted... hmm.

Comment: @shou I think questions are much riskier on meta than answers. try answering some questions here thoughtfully. Or, just ignore it, because "meta is meta.." and concentrate on the sites with real Q&A! http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: @radp Its more like, I want to have the power to do it... But not execute it necessarily... And I don't want people downvoting me when they disagree, sometimes to rather rational questions... :) (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66533/is-it-fine-if-i-post-a-link-to-a-question-as-a-question)

Comment: @Shou, that's a poor idea and thus earned you some well deserved downvotes. Read what Jeff linked :)

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, seems like I will do that, but sometimes it does become necessary for me to use the meta, and for such instances... Anyway, it was worth a shot... :)

Comment: @radp It was not a suggestion. It was more like a question. Can I do this? I should not expect to be downvoted because I asked a question certainly? That basically means to say, well you should be careful about what question you ask as it maybe interpreted as your intent or someone else's and u will pay bu losing ur rep!

Comment: Wait, since when does it take 125 rep to downvote?

Comment: @mmyers http://picasaweb.google.com/Shouvik.GR/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCLbg9tGqn-u-uQE#5524951803426604690

Answer (score 1):

You could consider posting another, more correct answer.