# Is it okay to repost a question that I already asked at another website?

Tags: discussion, reposts

Regarding this question

[Is it okay to repost a question from another website that was never answered there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68543/is-it-okay-to-repost-a-question-from-another-website-that-was-never-answered-the),

is it okay to repost a question which I have asked at another website (such as the Eclipse forums). It shouldn't be plagiarism, because it's my own question, but is this an "etiquette" violation?

Comment: Please post two way links in that case. So anybody who finds one version, can look up answers on the other version.

Comment: What about those posts on other SE sites? A PHP based question which so happens is related to WordPress being asked on both SO and WordPress Answers to benefit from responses on both accounts i.e. getting a PHP based response (a direct answer to the question) and a 'there is a plugin for that' style answers from WordPress... What if it wasn't answered on the other SE community? Does it warrant a repost elsewhere?

Answer (score 9):

It may also be helpful to consider improving the question in a way that ensures you get a better answer than those you received (or didn't receive) on the other site. If you didn't get a satisfactory answer there, you may want to indicate why (e.g. including details about solutions you were provided at the other site, and why those were unacceptable), or look more closely at your question and see if there are details you left out that made it harder for folks to help solve your problem. Especially if you received follow-up questions there from potential answerers, whether or not you answered them, etc.

As long as you form a complete question on SO, including a link to the "other" question to give people context might be a good idea, or adding it as a comment to your question at least.

Comment: Absolutely; if the question wasn't getting a good answer where it was, consider that the question may need some improvement before transplanting it to a new location.

Answer (score 7):

Some people get upset if they find the same user posting the same question to multiple forum sites *at the same time.* It can be annoying if I spend ten minutes answering your question on site A, and then find your question, already answered, on site B. It's even more annoying if I see if on site C, as well!

But if a question isn't answered on site A after a reasonable period of time, it seems fine to ask it on another site. And you could make the case that since SE isn't actually a forum, but rather a repository of knowledge, slightly different rules apply. Even if the question is answered elsewhere, it may belong here as well, to serve as a permanent record.

Comment: +1 for the "permenant record" statement

Answer (score 4):

Since you're the author and plagiarism isn't an issue, the only factor you should consider is quality. Stack Exchange welcomes all good questions, regardless of whether you've asked them elsewhere.

In this context, "good" depends on a number of things, including whether your question is on-topic, how well your question is formatted, the amount of background/supporting information you provide....