# Importing questions from another site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, self-answer

We currently run the site http://cookbook.hobocentral.net.  It contains a bunch of "questions" and "recipes" for the Hobo plugin for Ruby on Rails.  We're prepping the 2.0 release of Hobo, and part of that prep is to update our web presence.

One suggestion is just to move everything to Stack Overflow and then shut down the "cookbook" part of our site.

Is there a mechanism for moving over a carefully curated set of questions and answers that are still relevant? Would that be encouraged or discouraged?

Comment: are downvotes fair for the question like that? **"Is there a mechanism for moving over a carefully curated set of questions and answers that are still relevant? Would that be encouraged or discouraged?"**

Comment: @Bart I know the [meaning](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). For this question though these read to me not as disagreement but as _I didn't bother to read the question beyond the title_. None of dumbvoters bothered to think of whether their disagreement applies to "encouraged" or "discouraged" part

Comment: I would suggest updating the [wiki for hobo](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/hobo/info)

Comment: @gnat: downvote and discourage seem to have the same parity.

Comment: This discussion might be relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68543/is-it-okay-to-repost-a-question-from-another-website-that-was-never-answered-the

Answer (score 9):

Please don't just copy over your content. Yes, you are [allowed and encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) to answer your own questions, but this can be tricky. The same rules which apply to normal questions and answers also apply to self-answered questions, and users IMO tend to be more critical of them.

Though I haven't looked at it, more than likely at least part of the content will not be a perfect fit for SO. Recently people involved in another project did something similar and the community response to that was [not all that positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356613/what-is-the-new-ibm-social-business-toolkit).

Should Hobo get enough interest among developers, then questions about it will appear here organically. Answering those will be a far better approach than mechanically copying a bunch of content. By all means state on your website that you're an active SO user and will look for related questions.

Comment: Sure, hobo gets some questions on Stack OVerflow under the [hobo] tag.  They also sometimes go weeks without an answer.  The community is too small to properly support SO, our mailing list and our site.  My answers on SO often include the phrase "please repost on our mailing list, you will get more & better answers there".  We will continue to discourage the use of SO unless it can completely replace one of our previous support sites.

Comment: To clarify, the reason I encourage reposting to the mailing list is that by posting on SO you only help yourself, by posting to the mailing list you help the entire Hobo community, since it is the canonical location.   This contrasts strongly with larger communities such as rails or javascript, where a stack overflow question/answer is much more likely to be seen by others than a posting to a mailing list.

Comment: Isn't that a very backward approach? Don't post on SO, because that's not where the community is... How do you expect the community to grow here then? Any comments to that effect can only be counter-productive. If there are not enough people to answer, the popularity of your "product" might be at fault. Not SO in itself. That said, I never said you were not allowed to transfer some content. But be very very careful if you do. It has to be a good fit. If it isn't, expect downvotes or closevotes to happen. Making SO your primary support platform might not be a good idea. Just my opinion though.