# Is it impolite to repost someone's original question elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting, reposts

I saw a question asked that interests me on one of the Stack Exchange sites.
However, I would like a different perspective than that of the site it was posted on.

Is it considered impolite to repost on a separate SE site?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68543/is-it-okay-to-repost-a-question-from-another-website-that-was-never-answered-the

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange doesn't really allow for what is called "cross posting" (posting the same question multiple sites simply to increase exposure), but if you want to completely re-ask the question in the *context* of a different site, just make sure it is sufficiently different to make it clear why you felt it was a better fit for your preferred audience.

Simply cutting and pasting the original question will not likely be well received, but if you ask the question so it is more appropriate and more interesting for that *audience* specifically, that will likely be okay.

Comment: Further, cut/paste without attribution would be at best impolite, at worst a copyright violation.